# Geopandas read_file loads polygon data as lines

Tags: python, geopandas, jupyter-notebook

I am loading nfhl fema flood layer to geopandas via jupyter workbook and trying to isolate one state of data.

the code is

```
import geopandas as gpd
import folium
import pygeos

#load USA boundary data
us_bounds = gpd.read_file('input/tl_2022_us_state/tl_2022_us_state.shp')

#isolate specific state
ca = us_bounds[us_bounds['STUSPS'] == 'CA']

#load fema data and mask with ca
fema = gpd.read_file('input/NFHL_Key_Layers.gdb', layers='S_FLD_HAZ_AR', mask=ca)
```

The error comes in the image attached. The data should be polygons but the rendering and subsequent exporting as a .shp or .geojson shows these lines instead. It seems like this occurs on the read_file stage of fema. I am running the most recent versions of all loaded libraries.

[image]

Any ideas?

Data is sourced from
NFHL: https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/national-flood-hazard-layer-nfhl
US Boundary Data: https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2022/STATE/

Comment: The documentation about the data is probably this https://www.fema.gov/sites/default/files/documents/fema_FIRM-database-technical-reference_112021_0.pdf. If it is correct, please add it into your question. How does the layer look if you open it with the most recent QGIS version? And it would be nice if you could give a direct download link for getting the data.

Comment: when i load the data in QGIS is loads normally! thats why im so confused. the link to the data is added above

Comment: I suppose that geopandas is also reading the data with the GDAL driver https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/openfilegdb.html. The driver is reverse engineered and not perfect yet but improving. I would check first what GDAL version your geopandas version is using.